# What type of filter is the "French Low Pass Filter"?

Tags: audio, synthesizer, synthesis, plug-ins, filter

What kind of filter is a French Lowpass Filter?

In one example I know of, the Serum soft synth, there is a lowpass filter called the "French LP" under the "Misc" set of filters.

I suspect it may exist under a different name, possibly.  At first I thought it might be a Butterworth filter, but it would be a misnomer, because Butterworth was a British inventor.

I don't know of many popular French synthesizers, but there are undoubtedly French software-based filter designers.  Does anyone know what this filter might be modeled on?

More importantly, what differentiates it from a normal low pass filter?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of question to ask on the http://www.xferrecords.com/forum page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better answered by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

All I know is it seems to be a reference to french house, the "french touch," which is a filtered-disco sound.  Expect a prominent, musical filter, but I am not an expert on filter design so I can't separate out the marketing angle from the reality of what you will get.  Examples of the kind of music being referenced:

http://thesearepowerfulhours.com/frenchph.html